# isnull vs is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have noticed a number of queries at work and on SO are using limitations in the form:

```
isnull(name,'') <> ''
```

Is there a particular reason why people do that and not the more terse

```
name is not null
```

Is it a legacy or a performance issue?

Comment: Martin Smith is right if you're quoting the code accurately.  IF it's actually something like isnull(name,'') <> @name then you're keeping SQL from using any index but you're getting a result more like what Donnie describes

Comment: @Matt: Yes, I made a mistake in the code I gave in the example. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
where isnull(name,'') <> ''
```

is equivalent to

```
where name is not null and name <> ''
```

which in turn is equivalent to

```
where name <> ''
```

(if name `IS NULL` that final expression would evaluate to unknown and the row not returned)

The use of the `ISNULL` pattern will result in a scan and is less efficient as can be seen in the below test.

```
SELECT ca.[name],
       [number],
       [type],
       [low],
       [high],
       [status]
INTO   TestTable
FROM   [master].[dbo].[spt_values]
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT [name]
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT ''
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL) ca 


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TestTable ON dbo.TestTable(name)

GO


SELECT name FROM TestTable WHERE isnull(name,'') <> ''

SELECT name FROM TestTable WHERE name is not null and name <> ''
/*Can be simplified to just WHERE name <> '' */
```

Which should give you the execution plan you need.

[image]

Comment: "The use of this pattern...is less efficient..." The pattern being the use of ISNULL or the IS NULL...OR = construct?

Comment: @KarlKieninger - The pattern being the use of `ISNULL` - originally there were some execution plan images making this clearer. Will regenerate them..

Answer (score 17):

```
is not null
```

Will only check if the field is not null. If the field contains an empty string, then the field is no longer null.

```
isnull(name, '') <> name
```

Checks for both a null and an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

`isnull(name,'') <> :name` is shorthand for `(name is null or name <> :name)`  (assuming that `:name` never contains the empty string, thus why shorthands like this can be bad).

Performance-wise, it depends.  `or` statements in `where` clauses can give extremely bad performance.  However, functions on columns impair index usage.  As usual: profile.

Answer (score 1):

```
isnull(name,'') <> name
```

Well I can see them using this because this way if the name doesn't match or is null it returns as a failed comparison.  This really means: `name is null` or `name <> name`

Where as this one `name is not null` just checks to see if the name is null.

Answer (score 1):

They don't mean the same thing.

```
name is not null
```

This checks for records where the name field is null

```
isnull(name,'') <> name
```

This one changes the value of null fields to the empty string so they can be used in a comparision.  In SQL Server (but not in Oracle I think), if a value is null and it is used to compare equlaity or inequality it will not be considered becasue null means I don't know the value and thus is not an actual value. So if you want to make sure the null records are considered when doing the comparision, you need ISNULL or COALESCE(which is the ASCII STANDARD term to use as ISNULL doen't work in all databases).

What you should be looking at is the differnece between

```
isnull(a.name,'') <> b.name
```

a.name <> b.name

then you will understand why the ISNULL is needed to get correct results.

Answer (score 1):

I apparently misread your question. So let me strike my first answer and try this one:

```
isnull(name,'') <> ''
```

is a misguided shortcut for

```
name is not null and name <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the functional difference. As to the performance issue, in Postgres I've found that -- oh, I should mention that Postgres has a function "coalesce" that is the equivalent of the "isnull" found in some other SQL dialects -- but in Postgres, saying

```
where coalesce(foobar,'')=''
```

is significantly faster than

```
where foobar is null or foobar=''
```

Also, it can be awesomely dramatically faster to say

```
 where foobar>''
```

over

```
where foobar!=''
```

A greater than test can use the index and thus skip over all the blanks, while a not-equal test has to do a full file read. (Assuming you have an index on the field and no other index is used in preference.)

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to make use of the index on that column, use

```
name is not null and name <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

These two queries are not the same. For example, I do not have a middle name, this is a known fact, which can be stored as

```
MiddleName=''
```

However, if we don't know someone's middle name, we can store NULL.
So, ISNULL(MiddleName, '') means "persons without known middle names".

Answer (score 0):

It is to handle both the empty string and `NULL`. While it is good to be able to do with with one statement, `isnull` is proprietary syntax. I would write this using portable Standard SQL as

```
NULLIF(name, '') IS NOT NULL
```