# Differences between "IS NULL" and "ISNULL()" in Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, null

Is there any difference in performance between the operator `IS NULL` and the function `ISNULL()`?

Comment: Pretty much the same, I think. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking into the MySQL manual, they seem to be synonyms really.

- [MySQL manual on `IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null)
- [MySQL manual on `ISNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)

and even if they aren't, I would tend to trust the query optimizer to pick the best solution.

Comment: I readed that too, but the ISNULL doc says that SHARES some special behaviors with IS NULL, that scared me.

Comment: @Wiliam good point. Maybe doing a test run is indeed the best way to go!

Comment: Huh? In my understanding, "shares special behaviour" just means they're weird, but they're weird in the *same way*.

Comment: @Wiliam, `isnull()` seems like a function, whereas `is null` is surely a "language feature".

Answer (score 15):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118213/isnull-vs-is-null) is similar, though not exactly on MySQL. According to the test shown there:

**`IS NULL` is more efficient as it doesn't require a scan.**

Seek is generally faster than a scan as it only includes qualifying records, while scan includes every row. It is explained in more detail [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/30/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-table-scan/).

Another difference (though it's not performance) is their negation syntax:

```
IS NOT NULL  /* using NOT operator */
! ISNULL()  /* using exclamation mark */
```

Comment: Newbie warning; this is only more efficient if the column is indexed :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck, If it isn't indexed which would you use?

Comment: The thread you're referring to is about MSSQL where `isnull` is not the same as MySQL `isnull` but the same as MySQL `ifnull`. So the answer overall is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: `NOT ISNULL()` also valid statement