# Handling NULLs in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

What is the right practice of checking NULLs in SQL Case ?

1) **Using ISNULL()**

```
WHEN (ISNULL(TABLE.COLUMN,0) > 0) THEN ....
```

2) **Using IS NULL**

```
WHEN TABLE.COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN ....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118213/isnull-vs-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking any condition then always use 'is null' and if replacing any value with a different one, then use isnull(a,b).
Check the following - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Read the last line specially!!!

Answer (score 1):

Second one is right if you want to check for null value in SQL case..

Answer (score 0):

This is also another approach to check for `NON NULL` values.

Checking for length of the column if it is greater than 1 or equal 1 then its a NON NULL
value.

```
declare @emp table
 (
 fname varchar(50)
 );

 INSERT into @emp VALUES('vishwanath');
 INSERT into @emp VALUES('chetan');
 INSERT into @emp VALUES(NULL);
 INSERT into @emp VALUES(NULL);

 SELECT * FROM @emp
 where len(fname)>=1 and fname<>'';

 Gives..

     fname
--------------------------------------------------
    vishwanath
    chetan
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO @emp VALUES('')` - what about this one then? It is not NULL, just empty.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct if the values in the column are either greater than 0 or null. 
You can refer to this [post](http://allwrong.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/sql-when-case-null-fails/) if you want to know about the weird behavior of nulls in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

when you are checking whether a column is null or not it is better to use
 col IS NULL

when you use   `ISNULL(TABLE.COLUMN,0) > 0)` function , null values have to be converted to zero fist then should take all values greater than zero

this function is useful in another occasion. lets say if I want to return all the null values as well as the negative values.

so the query would be

```
select * from table where col is null or col<0
```

this can be re-written as

```
select * from table isnull(col,-1)<0
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct in there cause, however ISNULL can be helpfull when you want to use a constant value instead of NULL in that column while calculating SUM, average, etc.
For example you can check  :http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Due to this feature I personally use ISNULL/COALESCE for calculation purposes.